# What actually are thoughts?

Tags: human-biology, brain, memory

The human brain consists of neurons that transmit impulses like wires that conduct electricity.I am confused about where are our thoughts stored and what really are thoughts? For example if I think about space, what is actually happening in my brain, and in what form is my memory that there are black holes in space, stored?

After doing a little bit of research I somehow came to the conclusion that thoughts are nothing but the electro-chemical reactions that are triggered by external stimuli and Hippocampus is responsible for storing long term memory. But I was unable to understand what the following paragraph means:

> "The hippocampus helps to solidify the pattern of connections that form a memory but the memory itself depends on the solidification of connections between the individual brain cells".

Please explain it. Am I correct so far? Please help.

Comment: In short -  it's more complicated than that ;)

Comment: @Mithoron, am I correct when I say that thoughts are nothing but the electro-chemical reactions that are triggered by external stimuli, ?

Comment: I think we don't know how thoughts arise from incredible amount of chemical reactions in brain. And of course internal stimuli are important.

Comment: @Mithoron, Can you please frame an answer explaining the above paragraph, :)?

Comment: I know nothing about neuroscience! Your question is on-topic here but I thought I would let you know that your question would also be a very good fit for [CognitiveScience.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not just hippocampus, but even cortex is involved.

Comment: But what are thoughts? :) I don't think the question is well defined yet. If you indicate a specific "thought" or "thought process" in mind, you may get a better answer.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The question is still ambiguous. Memory can be explained as done below in terms of short-term memory by @WYSIWYG. Long-term memory, and 'thoughts' are a whole other matter and involve large areas of the cortex, as mentioned by WYSIWG. This question needs work.

Comment: What does the "black holes" part mean?

Comment: @HDE226868 OP's reference to black holes isn't important. I think it should be read as "How is my knowledge of some arbitrary fact, *X*, stored?"

Answer (score 2):

> The hippocampus helps to solidify the pattern of connections that form a memory but the memory itself depends on the solidification of connections between the individual brain cells".

This refers to the phenomenon called [Long Term Potentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_potentiation) which regulates synaptic strength between neurons. Certain patterns of firing (high frequency) causes the post synaptic neuron to strengthen the synapses. One way of doing that is by increasing the number of receptors (Usually NMDA receptors). Due to this, the response would be stronger in the next firing event. You can imagine its effects- more number of times you read a passage better will you remember it.

Hippocampus is involved in this process (it is one region where a lot of synaptic dynamics happens) but consolidation and long term storage of memories is handled by the cortex. Essentially what happens when a memory is formed is strengthening of synapses.

Comment: Thanks @WYSIWYG, but I could not understand what "...patterns of firing.." means.

Comment: @Abdullah Pattern means the how the frequently and at what intensity is the synaptic signal given. I said patterns because in certain cases continuous firing can also cause weakening of synapses. This is called Long Term Depression.

Comment: +1.Moving on to my original question,is it yet to be discovered what thoughts are and in which form are they stored?

Comment: @Abdullah To an extent. The term "thought", itself is quite broad.